# Order post type by sum of two custom fields

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, query-posts

I have a custom post type for vouchers. I've added two custom fields to this post type named "value_1" and "value_2". They both contain a number. (The first value will be applied at checkout, the second one is a mail-in rebate, that's why there are two values.)

Now, for the user, the sum of these two values is of the most interest. That's why I would like to make a query that sorts my posts based on the sum of "value_1" and "value_2". Can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Yes but not in an easy simple way via the order parameters.

I would suggest that you:

- Maintain a 3rd post meta
- Whenever you change the first or second, add them together and set the 3rd meta to contain the sum of the new values
- Order by the 3rd value

The alternative is to write your own SQL query from scratch and all the horrors and disadvantages that come with it

Comment: Yes, I thought of that. If there's no more elegant way then I'll just do that.

Comment: This would be the simplest most efficient method, it trades a minor amount of memory space in the mysql database for the speed of not having to do the calculation, and the convenience of not having to hack your way through `WP_Query` internals